# Box doesn't roll in Bullet Physics

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, bullet

As you can see in the image, The Box doesn't roll but slides on the slope.

[image]

Here is how i create the box in code,

```
config = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(config);
broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
bWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, config);
bWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -9.8f, 0));

// ...

btTransform t;
t.setIdentity();
t.setOrigin(btVector3(position.x, position.y, position.z));

btBoxShape* box = new btBoxShape(btVector3(size.x, size.y, size.z));
btVector3 inertia(0, 0, 0);
float mass = 10.f;
box->calculateLocalInertia(mass, inertia);

btMotionState* mState = new btDefaultMotionState(t);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo cInfo(mass, mState, box);
//cInfo.m_restitution = 0.4f;
//cInfo.m_friction = 0.5f;
btRigidBody* body = new btRigidBody(cInfo);
//body->setLinearFactor(btVector3(1,1,0));
//body->setAngularFactor(btVector3(0,0,1));
m_impl->bWorld->addRigidBody(body);
```

I tried with friction and other parameters but result is the same. Let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your `inertia` vector to `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo`.
Check the 4th parameter on `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo` constructor (the one with default value).